# Intl.DateTimeFormat inconsistent between Chrome/Node and Firefox

Tags: javascript, datetime

Given the following code:

```
const foo = new Intl.DateTimeFormat('en-GB', {
  hourCycle: 'h12',
  timeStyle: 'short',
  dateStyle: 'short',
}).format(1650442310319);
```

The output in Chrome/Node is `20/04/2022, 09:11 am` whilst the output in Firefox is `20/04/2022, 9:11 am`. Notice the leading `0` on the hour being inconsistent.

One way to fix this for this `en-GB` locale is:

```
const bar = new Intl.DateTimeFormat('en-GB', {
  day: '2-digit',
  month: '2-digit',
  year: 'numeric',
  hourCycle: 'h12',
  hour: 'numeric',
  minute: '2-digit',
}).format(1650442310319);
```

Now the output in both browsers is `20/04/2022, 9:11 am`. However, this breaks formatting by locale. For example if I switch to `en-US`, the string we'd want is `4/20/2022, 9:11 am` but we actually get `04/20/2022, 9:11 am` because we specified 2 digits for the day and month.

It looks like the ideal solution would be to combine the approaches, such as:

```
const foo = new Intl.DateTimeFormat('en-GB', {
  hourCycle: 'h12',
  hour: 'numeric',
  minute: '2-digit',
  dateStyle: 'short',
}).format(1650442310319);
```

But alas this is not possible. As the MDN docs say:

> Note: dateStyle can be used with timeStyle, but not with other options
> (e.g. weekday, hour, month, etc.).

So is there any way to use this native datetime formatter consistently, without sacrificing the benefits of formatting by locale, which is one of the primary purposes of it?

Comment: The *toLocale* methods are implementation dependent. They are supposed to follow the formats at the [*Unicode Common Locale Data Repository* project](https://cldr.unicode.org). However, there really is no set standard for many timestamp formats used in different places. In particular, the *toLocaleDate* methods should never be used where an exact format is required because they aren't guaranteed to be consistent across implementations. If you want precise formatting, do it manually (a library can help).

Comment: BTW, the *toLocale* methods don't format by locale, the primary formatting designator is a BCP47 language tag, so it's by language. Naming the parameter "locale" is a misnomer promulgated by the authors of the ECMA-402 standard.

Comment: Would seem a bit strange to provide a native method to format datetime strings in quite specific ways, but have no standard to follow and therefore be implemented inconsistently. It can cause hydration errors between server and browser for example.

Comment: It would be a very bad design decision to rely on *toLcoale* formatting of dates for an API between systems. As you've discovered, there are ambiguities between available options and supposed language–based formats that are resolved more or less arbitrarily. For example, it might be common to expect an en-GB date order to be day, month, year yet the date on the masthead of that very British publication [*The Times*](https://www.thetimes.co.uk) is month, day, year.

Comment: @RobG are you suggesting Intl.DateTimeFormat isn't a very useful method, since we can't rely on it to provide a consistent output between browsers, and we can't always rely on it to output a format correct for the locale? (e.g. as you say British publications use a different format for mastheads). So we should only use it if we don't care too much about what the user sees, and don't need to worry about cross-system consistency, e.g. server-client hydration, unit tests, E2E tests

Comment: Yes. It's only intended to present formatted data to users. To me the only useful bits are the *formatToParts* method for getting the individual values to arrange and format as required, and the *timeZone* option to get values for a particular place.